# How to restore healthy Unity after incomplete update

Tags: unity, updates

I updated my Ubuntu and while it was restarting command line appeared and froze, then I forced shutdown PC and when Ubuntu booted again, I saw unity is corrupted.
Launcher and menus disappeared but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and Righ-Click menu works.
Also I can open Firefox and other apps through terminal.
This is how my current desktop:

[image]

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset Compiz configurations

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

Try to completely remove your ATI drivers from your system:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

Remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Reinstall xorg completely

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
```

Re-configure Xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

by Bruno Pereira

Now you should reconfigure Unity. It will remove Unity completely.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging
apt-get install unity
```

Install Unity again.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo reboot
```

by Justinas Dūdėnas and mpm

It works for me just great.

Answer (score 0):

**For 12.04 and older:**

```
unity --reset
```

run this command it will fix the problem,but not perfectly,running `unity --reset` will reset all of the launcher options, but it won't remove your custom favorites. To also remove any launchers you've added to the launcher, run

```
unity --reset-icons
```

Or manually by:

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

I would recommend running the gsettings command before `unity --reset`, so that you won't have to restart unity for the gsettings key reset to take effect.

http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-reset-unity-to-default-settings-in-ubuntu/

Comment: `--reset` is now deprecated..