# Problem after Logging screen. Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, desktop-background

I have some problem with my **Ubuntu 13.04**, after installing it with **Oracle VM Virtual Box**.

So, after I have installed it, I reboot my virtual machine, and I saw the Log - in screen. But when I typed my login and password, the screen became dark 
and I got this error 'The system is running in low-graphics mode' .

To solve this problem, I have found many information on different forums. Using this link

> [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

I tried to install the driver on my Video card. It should be noted, that I have two videocards on my laptop:

1. AMD Radeon HD HD7670M
2. simple Intel video card

So, firstly I tried to install ATI drivers. And after logging in screen I could see the standart wallpaper of Ubuntu, also I could click the Right button on the mouse 
standart menu was opened, where I could choose one of this: create a folder, create a document, change the wallpaper etc. **BUT NOTHING ELSE!!!**

When I tried to install the Intel drivers, I got the same result.

What is the problem?

Please, try to help me!

Comment: I have this issue too and posted it [here][1] but nobody answered me.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/304324/how-to-restore-healthy-unity-after-incomplete-update

Answer (score 0):

Try to completely remove your ATI drivers from your system:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

Remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Reinstall xorg completely

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
```

Re-configure Xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

by [Bruno Pereira](https://askubuntu.com/users/25863/bruno-pereira)

Now you should reconfigure Unity.
It will remove Unity completely.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging
apt-get install unity
```

Install Unity again.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo reboot
```

by [Justinas Dūdėnas](https://askubuntu.com/users/39909/justinas-ddnas) and [mpm](https://askubuntu.com/users/42179/mpm)

It works for me just great.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it.

Comment: It didn't help.
When I tried to reinstall xorg completely, I had a message that such catalogs wasn't found.

Comment: Yes, I had it too, but follow the instruction to the end.

Comment: My laptop has ati 7670 and core i7 CPU, I try a lot of solutions and It's the only one that works fine.

Comment: I tried to do it one more time. But it didn't help. As a result, after logging, I obtain a dark screen with a cursor, and after some time there appears a message about an internal error in Ubuntu 13.04.
Maybe there could be something else? Maybe another error or I missed something. What do you think?

Comment: Could You describe all process of installing Your Ubuntu, please? For example version of Ubuntu, installing process, what You had seen when starting Your Ubuntu at first time, Your actions to 'repair' the system, everything what could be essential for me.

Comment: Before I do them, I had use this:

   dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

Comment: Also I made a little change to the instruction (for make it exactly like what I did). Do that again precisely and remember never use AMD driver again until driver's bug gets fixed.