# Nvidia 840M driver installation Acer E5-571

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, xorg, hybrid-graphics

After a lot of trying and installing I don't know anything more to I can do to get this running.

I am having trouble installing the current Nvidia proprietary driver `346.35` on a `Nvidia 840M` graphics card, in combinations with an `Intel i5-4210U` cpu, kernel `3.13.0-45` on `Ubuntu 14.04.1 64 bit`

After installing the driver (manually from Nvidia driver page) and restarting lightdm / rebooting I get to the login screen and everything is looking normal. Once I login the screen resolution gets distorted and nothing more than "System program problem detected" is displayed, Unity / Compiz do not load.

I also tried installing the NVIDIA drivers from edgers `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`. After a reboot you hear the Ubuntu starting sound but the screens stays black.

The only thing you can do in both cases is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F1</kbd> and uninstall all nvidia drivers to get the Ubuntu desktop loading.

Solutions that did not work:

- [Problems after upgrading to 14.04 (only background and pointer after login)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login)
- [How to restore healthy Unity after incomplete update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304324/how-to-restore-healthy-unity-after-incomplete-update)

I've never had any trouble installing the proprietary Nvidia driver on linux before, maybe someone can help me here. The image below shows the bad screen resolution after login.

[image: Bad screen resolution after login]

Comment: Sorry this leads to the same black screen problem I have mentioned. So no duplication here.

Comment: Okay now the strangest thing is that if I let the Laptop sit at the login screen (black screen) for around 30 minutes, suddenly the screen turns on and everything is working?!

Comment: Voting to re-open...

Comment: @Fabby so you are having a similar issue?

Comment: No, I solved my issue a long time ago... (I also run a different NVidia then you) I just think your Q&A adds some new information to the site specifically for the 840M...  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I have finally found a solution for the problem!

Thanks to these threads:

- http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/549534/nvidia-drivers-how-to-install-it-in-ubuntu-14041204/
- http://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/2gk0dh/problem_with_installing_nvidia_drivers_on_840m/

### **The solution is:**

When the computer has booted up and you see the black screen press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>  and log in with your user account.

Edit your *xorg.conf* with `sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Find the line that says: Section `"Screen"`

Insert a new line that says `UseDisplayDevice "DFP"`

Save with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and
exit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

---

Next install bumblebee with `sudo apt-get install bumblebee`.

Then reboot `sudo reboot`

Comment: Thanks for your hint I didn't want to look arrogant, accepting my own answer ;)

Comment: It's a good answer that will probably help someone who has a similar problem with the NVIDIA 840M driver.