# No additional driver listed for Nvidia GPU - 14.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.10

Specs:

- Intel® Core™ i5-3570K CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4
- GTX 980, but appears as VESA: GM204 Board
- 64bit

When I try to install the proprietary drivers none are listed.  When I enter `lspci -v` into terminal I get this:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 980] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])    
Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 2980  
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16  
Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]    
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]   
Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]    
I/O ports at e000 [size=128]    
Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]    
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Entering `ubuntu-drivers devices` returns nothing, however.

When I install the drivers from xorg-edgers PPA it fails and I cannot get unity to start on a reboot.

Comment: The xorg-edgers gives you a lot of driver versions...  Which versions did you try?

Comment: I used versions 340 and 343, as well as current.

Comment: 343 has been removed in the mean time as it was causing problems. Did you have a look over here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/580075/nvidia-840m-driver-installation-acer-e5-571 as this guy seems to have found a solution I've never seen before...

Answer (score 0):

Very same problem with GTX 750 after upgrade 14.04 -> 14.10. Installed official 346 driver manually - works like a charm with ~5% performance boost (as tested with Unigine Tropics benchmark). You didn't ask the question but assuming you're looking for a solution I recommend you to do the same.